# How can I convert back and forth between Blob and Image in Flutter Web?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, dart-html

#### Context

I use image_picker with Flutter web to allow users to select an image.  This returns the URI of a local network Blob object, which I can display with `Image.network(pickedFile.path)`.  Where I get into trouble is when I want to start manipulating that image.  First, I need to pull it off the network and into memory.  When I'm done, I need to push it back up to a network-accessible Blob.

#### How do I create a Blob from an Image?

I don't mean the built-in Image widget.  I mean an ImageLib.Image where ImageLib is the [Dart image library](https://pub.dev/packages/image).  Why do I want to do this?  Well, I have a web app in which the user selects an image, which is returned as a Blob.  I bring this into memory, use ImageLib to crop and resize it, and then want to push it back up to a Blob URL.  This is where my code is currently:

```
# BROKEN:
var png = ImageLib.encodePng(croppedImage);
var blob = html.Blob([base64Encode(png)], 'image/png');
var url = html.Url.createObjectUrl(blob);
```

The code does not throw an error until I try to display the image with `Image(image: NetworkImage(url))`.  The error begins with:

> The following Event$ object was thrown resolving an image frame:

Copying and pasting `url` into the browser reveals a black screen, which I take to be a 0x0 image.  And so I come to my questions:

1. How do I properly encode the image and create a Blob?
2. Is there a better way to manipulate images in Flutter web besides using Blobs?  I am basically only using it because that is what image_picker_for_web returns, and so it is the only method I know aside from possibly using a virtual filesystem, which I haven't explored too much.

#### How do I pull an image into memory?

While I'm at it, I might as well ask what is the best practice for bringing an image into memory.  For mobile, I used `image_picker` to get the name of a file, and I would use the `package:image/image.dart as ImageLib` to manipulate it:

```
// pickedfile.path is the name of a file
ImageLib.Image img = ImageLib.decodeImage(File(pickedfile.path).readAsBytesSync());
```

With web I don't have filesystem access, so I've been doing this instead:

```
// pickedfile.path is the URL of an HTML Blob
var response = await http.get(pickedfile.path);
ImageLib.Image img = ImageLib.decodeImage(response.bodyBytes);
```

This is considerably slower than the old way, probably because of the GET.  Is this really the best (or only) way to get my image into memory?

Comment: have a same problem, did you solve this?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The secret, as [suggested](https://github.com/rylandely/shoot-web/blob/master/lib/helpers/image_helpers.dart) by Brendan Duncan, was to use the browser's native decoding functionality:

```
  // user browser to decode
  html.ImageElement myImageElement = html.ImageElement(src: imagePath);
  await myImageElement.onLoad.first; // allow time for browser to render
  html.CanvasElement myCanvas = html.CanvasElement(width: myImageElement.width, height: myImageElement.height);
  html.CanvasRenderingContext2D ctx = myCanvas.context2D;

  //ctx.drawImage(myImageElement, 0, 0);
  //html.ImageData rgbaData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, myImageElement.width, myImageElement.height);

  // resize to save time on encoding
  int _MAXDIM = 500;
  int width, height;
  if (myImageElement.width > myImageElement.height) {
    width = _MAXDIM;
    height = (_MAXDIM*myImageElement.height/ myImageElement.width).round();
  } else {
    height = _MAXDIM;
    width = (_MAXDIM*myImageElement.width/ myImageElement.height).round();
  }
  ctx.drawImageScaled(myImageElement, 0, 0, width, height);
  html.ImageData rgbaData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);

  var myImage = ImageLib.Image.fromBytes(rgbaData.width, rgbaData.height, rgbaData.data);
```

He proposed a similar trick for encoding, but for my use case it was sufficient to do it with Dart:

```
  int width, height;
  if (myImageElement.width > myImageElement.height) {
    width = 800;
    height = (800*myImageElement.height/ myImageElement.width).round();
  } else {
    height = 800;
    width = (800*myImageElement.width/ myImageElement.height).round();
  }
  ctx.drawImageScaled(myImageElement, 0, 0, width, height);
  html.ImageData rgbaData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
  var myImage = ImageLib.Image.fromBytes(rgbaData.width, rgbaData.height, rgbaData.data);
```

Note that in both cases I resize the image first to reduce the size.

Comment: how can I send it to server Multipart with dio?

Comment: I am uploading to Firebase.  I first encode the image as above and then:

```
  // encode as jpg
  String contentType = 'image/jpeg';
  var jpg = ImageLib.encodeJpg(img, quality: 90);

  // upload to firebase storage
  String url;
  try {
    fb.StorageReference _storage = fb.storage().ref(imageKey);
    fb.UploadTaskSnapshot uploadTaskSnapshot = await _storage.put(jpg, fb.UploadMetadata(contentType: contentType)).future;
    var imageUri = await uploadTaskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
    url = imageUri.toString();
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
```

Comment: It'd would be really great of you if you could put a complete solution, it is sparse and hard to follow. As for me I'm unable to use your solution to load blob image in memory.